# Sum string in sql

Tags: sql, string

I have a table:

```
Id Name
1  phucuong
2  ksks
3  na
```

I want output is:

```
phucuongksksna
```

how to write in sql?

I tried `concat`, but it is not working.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT Name AS [text()] FROM YourTable FOR XML PATH ('')
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR '') FROM YourTable
```

Another Solution SQL Server

```
SELECT STUFF  
(  
  (  
    SELECT ','+ CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(g.Name)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
    FROM YourTable g,YourTable e   
    WHERE g.Id=e.Id  
    FOR XMl PATH('')  
   ),1,1,''  
)
```

Comment: Both of the MSSQL suggestions made here are obsolete and inefficient. Always prefer `STRING_AGG`, which has been supported for 6 years now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

In both a SQL Server DB and a Postgres DB, we can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(name,'') FROM yourtable;
```

In Oracle DB, we can use `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(name) FROM yourtable; -- or LISTAGG(name,''), both will do
```

In MariaDB, the same query like in MYSQL will work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '') FROM yourtable;
```

In SQLite DB, it's very similar to the previous one:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name,'') FROM yourtable;
```

Of course, there are also other possibilities/functions to achieve this, but as far as I know, these are the most efficient options.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
       STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + name
    FROM table A1
    WHERE A1.ID = A2.ID FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') AS aliasName
```